# Nothing is visible in the VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

This problem appeared by itself[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1qPl.png). Everything was fine and at one point it started working unreal. Checked the laptop for viruses, reinstalled vscode, but nothing changed. This problem only affects vsсode, as all other programs work fine (without this defect). Please tell me what can be done.
Thank you!

Checked the laptop for viruses and reinstalled vscode

Comment: looks like a variant of graphics acceleration, disable it by command line parameter or setting